# Lightning Component Storing Date Attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Greetings and thank you in advance!

my component has the following:

```
<aura:attribute name="today" type="Date" /> 
<!-- more stuff -->
Date: <ui:outputDate value="{!v.today}" format="EEEE MMMM d" />
```

upon initialization I would like to be able to store the current date so I can display to the user..  Would also like to be able to advance this date via the next function and a button ( not shown)..

```
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    var today = new Date();
    component.set('v.today', currDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (currDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + currDate.getDate());
},
Next : function(component, event, helper) {
    var today = new Date(component.get('v.today'));

    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    // check to see if saturday or sunday if so forward past
    // forward on weekends
    if(today.getDay() == 6 ) {
        today.setDate(today.getDate() + 2);
    }

},
```

This code works fine in the lightning developer mode on my machine and android salesforce1 but does not work on an Ipad runnind salesforce1.

When the date is updated via the Next method in salesforce1 on an ipad the result format looks like

NaN-NaN-NaN

Believe this has to do with the date being constructed differently during the new Date( component.get('v.today')); call.

Is the way I am storing my date problematic on iOs salesforce1 or something else going on here??  Seems to be device OS related.  Insights welcome!

Thank you!!

Comment: appears that doing 

var today = new Date(component.get('v.today').replace(/-/g, '/'));  seems to fix the problem.. is this best practice?